# OpenShift : force HTTP instead of HTTPS for Arduino access

Tags: python, .htaccess, arduino, openshift

My OpenShift Python app works fine from any browser, except from my Arduino board that want to use to feed data into the app.  When I send a GET request to the app, I get a "302 Found" with a redirect to HTTPS, which is not supported by Arduino.
I've tried to use the Apache Rewrite engine to force HTTP, without success.
Looks like I should prevent the HTTPS redirection in the first place, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work for both. I actually force to https.

Comment: Just rewrote my question.  Any suggestion ?

Comment: We need more information. Show some code. How are you processing the request when it works?